# JavaScript - why json stringify not working?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Why `jsonObject.msg` is `undefined`? even i am getting value as `{"msg":"not_inserted"}` from `response.farewell`.

( FYI: where response.farewell is Google chrome apps generated JSON value `sendMessage("{\"msg\" : \"" + tmp + "\"}");` )

```
//var reply ='{"msg":"not_inserted"}';
//var jsonstring = JSON.parse(reply);
//console.log('>>> ' , jsonstring.msg); // it WORKS!


try {
    console.log("REPLY: ", response.farewell); 

    // it FAILS!!
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(response.farewell);        
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);        
    console.log('>>> ' , jsonObject.msg);

  } catch(eio) {        
    console.log(eio);
  }
```

**Output:**

```
REPLY: {"msg":"not_inserted"}
>>> undefined
```

Expected output:

`>>> not_inserted`

Comment: I tried that, but still same, value is undefined.

Comment: Have you tried `response.farewell.msg`? without using `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Still same it shows `undefined` when i tried response.farewell.msg

Comment: in my console i can see Google app is sending me as `{"msg":"not_inserted"}exit`

Comment: Is `tmp` a variable ?

Comment: `tmp` is external C# application sending a value "not_inserted" in JSON format.

Comment: What is `response.farewell` initially?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15446296/ - here you can see the response initial.

Comment: Are you including extra quotes `"` at `\"" + tmp + "\"` ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/okMLbjk.png - yes extra quotes else Google app fails.

Comment: response.farewell doesn't seem to be an object... I get `"REPLY:  Object {msg: "not_inserted"}"` on my side if I use `response = { farewell: { "msg": "not_inserted" } }`

Comment: Note: you don't have to serialize it yourself! You should just use `sendMessage({msg: tmp})`. Also, _please don't use that stupid "farewell" property from the example_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quotes to wrap string passed to `sendMessage`, removing extra double quotes

```
sendMessage('{\"msg\" : \"' + tmp + '\"}')
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fdLUl3X.png - when i trying to apply your were in Java, its syntax error.

Comment: @YumYumYum The images are not reproducible. If possible can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle to demonstrate ? See https://jsfiddle.net/t2opa459/2/

Comment: Thanks it works. so my `tmp` was broken i fixed it like you said.

Comment: Down-vote was not by me, someone else did i have still +1 there with accepted answer. thank you.